# Selenium + python непонятная ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, macos

Запускаю selenium на маке

```
import pyodbc
```

и вот такая ошибка валится:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-38-darwin.so
Reason: image not found
```

но через `pip List` видно, что данный модуль установлен. Кто-то сталкивался?

Comment: Может у вас несколько питонов на компе? Типичная в общем-то ситуация. Библиотеку вы поставили в одно окружение, а запускаете другое. Ну, например.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pyodbc` это только обертка над `unixodbc`. Т.е. это набор функций оформленный в виде pypi пакета, а под капотом использует библиотеку `unixodbc`. Поэтому, pip показывает, что pyodbc установлен, но системная зависимость, а именно файл `/usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib` не загрузился. То ли его там нет, то ли какая-то из его зависимостей отсутствует.

Если файл на месте посмотрите все ли его зависимости тоже на месте:

```
otool -L /usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
```

Скорее всего сама `unixodbc` или что-то из зависимостей не установлены.

Answer (score 1):

@Roman Konoval Спасибо. Вот и решение: brew install unixodbc